# can't file iphlpapi.lib on a c++ server application

Tags: c++, c

I wrote an app that uses the function IcmpSendEcho2Ex that is included in iphlpapi.lib
on the computer that I wrote it, it works and on another computer
but the computer that needs to use the app, there's an error that IcmpSendEcho2Ex needs the file iphlpapi.lib, and can't be found.

I tried looking for the file and all I can find was iphlpapi.dll
how can I get the app to work?

the computer that I'm trying to make I work on is windows XP

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the function `IcmpSendEcho2Ex` is only supported for Windows Vista SP1 and upwards. It doesn't exist on Windows XP.

If your application allows it, try using [`IcmpSendEcho2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead, which *does* exist on Windows XP.

Comment: thank you, I thought I saw the this function works on win 2000 and up. the problem is I need the "SourceAddress" for my app and IcmpSendEcho2 does not have it. how can I achieve this?

Comment: @ro-E Sorry, I don't know of an alternative off the top of my head, but will do some research and see what I can find.